# Can I represent POJO with List of Objects as a pivot manner

Tags: java

On my POJO implementation

```
Class Employee {
 Integer empId;
 String empName;
 List<Allowance> allowances;
 List<Deduction> deductions;  

//getter and setter

 public Employee(Integer empId, String empName, 
    List<Allowance> allowances,    List<Deduction> deductions) {
  this.empId = empId;
  this.empName  = empName;
  this.allowances = allowances;
  this.deductions = deductions;
 }
}


Class Allowance {
 Integer allwId;
 Employee emp;
 String allwName; // Basic Pay, DA, HRA etc..
 float amount;
  //getter and setter
}

Class Deduction {
  Integer dedId;
  Employee emp;
  String dedName; // FBS, Loan, Tax etc..
  float amount;
 //getter and setter
}
```

For example, I have added 2 employees.
The list allws1 has amount for Basic Pay, DA, HRA and deds1 has amount for FBS, Tax.
The list allws2 has amount for Basic Pay, DA and deds2 has amount for FBS, Loan, Tax.
And assign these two each employees something like,

```
Employee emp1=new Employee(1,"Mickel", allws1, deds1);
Employee emp2=new Employee(2,"John", allws2, deds2);

List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employees.add(emp1); employees.add(emp2);
```

Can I represent List of employees on pivot manner like this,

---

|   empName  |  Basic Pay | DA  | HRA | FBS | Loan | Tax |

---

|   Mickel   |  1400      | 120 | 50  | 20  | 0    |  27 |

---

|   John    |  1200      | 120 |  0  | 20  | 105  |  23 |

---

Comment: If the existing questions doesn't unveil the information you need, then you can post a comment on the respective answer. Otherwise mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You already have collected the data within the data objects `Allowance` and `Deduction`. What you need is a different view on it. Therefore you can put them into a `JTable` or simply print it to the Console in the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to output the elements of the "employees" list in a specific manner.

To do so, you can `Override` the method [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) in the `Employee` class.

This method returns the `String` representation of your `Object`.

For example,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String bp = ""; // get the BP
    String da = ""; // get the DA
    // etc...
    return String.format("|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|", this.empId, bp, da, ...); // this line won't compile
}
```

After that, you can implement another method that will output the `Employee` List with a header.